# GitHub connected via Git Bash but not via Ubuntu Bash (WSL)

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can push my code to my remote GitHub repo via PowerShell or Git Bash, but when I try to do the same via Ubuntu Bash (WSL), I get the following error:

```
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe': 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Show **full verbose output** of push under Ubuntu (not only error message) and before it check used credentials - they can be wrong

Comment: I've updated the original post with the full message.

Comment: This looks like a configuration error: something (per-user or system config file?) defines `core.sshCommand` as a string that only works under Windows, and tries to use that in WSL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this command

```
git config --global core.sshCommand /mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe
```